# Values in if statements

Tags: javascript, html

I need to print out the informations from input statements. When I got the one author - it works. When I add the author, it gives me surnames of both, so its fine. The I add the third author it gives me first author surname and then the third author surname twice - it supposed to give me the first author, the second one and then the third author's surname. 
So the problem is - when I got three authors it should give me all authors' surnames, not the first one and then the third one twice.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang='pl'> 
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'>
    <title>Robot naukowy</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>

    <!-- dynamic form - script -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = Load;
var numberOfAuthors = 0;


function Load()
{
    document.getElementById('add_input').onclick = AddElement;
}

function AddElement()
{
    var element1 = document.createElement('input');
    var element2 = document.createElement('input');
    var element3 = document.createElement('input');
    var label1 = document.createElement('label');
    var label2 = document.createElement('label');
    var label3 = document.createElement('label');
    var button = document.createElement('input');

    var number = numberOfAuthors;

    label1.innerHTML = "</br>Next Author's Name "+"</br>";
    label1.setAttribute('id', 'authorNameLabel' + number);

    element1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    element1.setAttribute('id', 'authorName' + number);
    element1.setAttribute('placeholder', "author's name");
    label1.appendChild(element1);

    label2.innerHTML = "</br>Next Author's Initials " + "</br>";
    label2.setAttribute('id', 'authorInitialsLabel' + number);

    element2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    element2.setAttribute('id', 'authorInitials' + number);
    element2.setAttribute('placeholder', "Author's Initials...");
    label2.appendChild(element2);

    label3.innerHTML = "</br>Next Author's surname"  + '</br>';
    label3.setAttribute('id', 'authorSurnameLabel' + number);

    element3.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    element3.setAttribute('id', 'authorSurname' + number);
    element3.setAttribute('placeholder', "Author's surname...");
    label3.appendChild(element3);

    button.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeAuthor(' + number + ')');
    button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    button.setAttribute('id', 'removeAuthorButton' + number);
    button.setAttribute('value', 'Button');

    document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(label1);
    document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(label2);
    document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(label3);
    document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(button);

    numberOfAuthors++;
}


function removeELement(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    return elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}

function removeAuthor(authorId){
    removeELement("authorName"+authorId);
    removeELement("authorInitials"+authorId);
    removeELement("authorSurname"+authorId);
    removeELement("removeAuthorButton"+authorId);
    removeELement("authorNameLabel"+authorId);
    removeELement("authorInitialsLabel"+authorId);
    removeELement("authorSurnameLabel"+authorId);
    numberOfAuthors--;
    getText();
}

function getText(){

    console.log(numberOfAuthors);

    var div = document.getElementById("readyorder");

    var firstAuthorName = document.getElementById("firstAuthorName");
    var firstAuthorInitials = document.getElementById("firstAuthorInitials");
    var firstAuthorSurname = document.getElementById("firstAuthorSurname");
    // var secondAuthorSurname =   
    var authorSurname


    for(var authorId = 0 ; authorId < numberOfAuthors ; authorId++ ){

        var authorName = document.getElementById("authorName"+authorId);
        var authorInitials = document.getElementById("authorInitials" + authorId);
        authorSurname = document.getElementById("authorSurname" + authorId);


    }

    var publisher = document.getElementById("publisher");

    var page = document.getElementById("page");

    var pageOther = document.getElementById("pageOther");
    var pageOtherValue =  pageOther.value;

    if(pageOther.value!=""){
        pageOtherValue = "-" + pageOther.value;
    }else{
        pageOtherValue = "";
    }

    var year = document.getElementById("year");
    var secondAuthorSurname;
    if(authorId === 0) { 
        div.innerHTML = firstAuthorSurname.value + " (" + year.value + ", s."+page.value + pageOtherValue;
    }
    else if (authorId === 1) {
       div.innerHTML = firstAuthorSurname.value + " and " + authorSurname.value + " (" + year.value + ") ";

       //secondAuthorSurname = authorSurname.value;
    }

    else if (authorId === 2) {
        div.innerHTML = firstAuthorSurname.value + ", " + authorSurname.value + " and " + authorSurname.value + " (" + year.value + ") ";

    }
}

function handlePages(){

    var cboxPageRange = document.getElementById("cboxPageRange");

    if (cboxPageRange.checked){
        var pageOther = document.getElementById("pageOther");
        pageOther.style.display="block";
    }else{
        var pageOther = document.getElementById("pageOther");
        pageOther.style.display="none";
        pageOther.value="";
        getText();
    }

}



    </script>



    </head>
<body>

<div class='container'>

    <!-- header --> 
    <header>
        <img src="images/header.jpg" alt=""/>
    </header>

    <!-- static form 1 -->

    First Author's Name <br />
    <input type="text" id="firstAuthorName" /> <br />
    First Author's Initials <br />
    <input type="text" id="firstAuthorInitials" /> <br />
    First Author's Surname <br />
    <input type="text" id="firstAuthorSurname" /> <br />

    <!-- dynamic form -->

<input type="submit" value="Add author" id="add_input" />

<form name="add_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
</form>



<div id="readyorder"></div><br/>

    <!-- static form 2 -->

        Publisher<br />
        <input type="text" id="publisher"><br />
        Page<br />
        <input type="text" id="page">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cboxPageRange" value="pageRangeCheckbox" onclick="handlePages()">
        <input type="text" id="pageOther" class="pageOther">
        <br>
        Year<br>
        <input type="text" id="year"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sprawdź" onclick="getText()" /> <br/><br/>

       <!-- readyorder  -->

    <div id="readyorder"></div><br/>

    <!-- sidebar --> 
    <aside>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Powrot do strony głownej</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Zmien styl</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>


    <!-- main -->
    <section id="main">
        <h1> You made your order</h1><br/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras condimentum tempus mi, maximus volutpat urna sollicitudin vitae. Vivamus rutrum mi sit amet commodo rutrum. Suspendisse potenti. Sed a ullamcorper eros. Maecenas dapibus erat mi, a egestas ipsum cursus volutpat. Aliquam posuere mi at consectetur convallis. Cras vitae ligula eget leo ultrices hendrerit nec sed ex. Morbi at ipsum rhoncus, dictum elit in, consectetur lorem. Aliquam suscipit diam sit amet mauris luctus, a egestas magna pharetra. Donec laoreet viverra risus nec fermentum. Maecenas gravida lectus vel ante commodo bibendum. Donec ac pellentesque mi. </p>
    </section>

    <!-- footer -->
    <footer>
        <p>Lukasz  © 2017</p>
    </footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not exactly related, but [looping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code) might save a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Too much text won't fit to comment, then put it to answer.

It seems you mistaked here:

```
for(var authorId = 0 ; authorId < numberOfAuthors ; authorId++ ){

    var authorName = document.getElementById("authorName"+authorId);
    var authorInitials = document.getElementById("authorInitials" + authorId);
    authorSurname = document.getElementById("authorSurname" + authorId);
}
```

After end of the loop you will have `authorName`, `authorInitials` and `authorSurname` will have a values of last(3rd) `authorId`. I think, you closed loop too early.